# SystemInAppBrowser NoSuchElementException while opening an url

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm currently developing a Cordova Android app. When I try to open a Play Store link from my app, nothing happens when I click on the link. Normally, it should open in the browser or the app itself if it's installed. However, I'm encountering an below error.

```
2023-05-30 12:28:10.829  E/PluginManager: Uncaught exception from plugin
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser.parseFeature(InAppBrowser.java:348)
    at org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser.execute(InAppBrowser.java:120)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:117)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:58)
    at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:186)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```